# Underline the single line of text from the paragraph in PHPEXCEL

Tags: phpexcel

How to underline a single line of text from the paragraph in the single column using PHPEXCEL

Answer (score 6):

Try this

for native php

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('b4')->getFont()->setUnderline(true);
```

for Codeigniter

```
$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('b4')->getFont()->setUnderline(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's just a single block of text in a cell, and not the entirety of the content of the cell, then you need to define the content of that cell as Rich Text

There's an example of setting a cell with Rich Text in `/Examples/02types.php`

```
$objRichText = new PHPExcel_RichText();
$objRichText->createText("Hello ");

$objUnderlined = $objRichText->createTextRun("underlined");
$objUnderlined->getFont()->setUnderline(true);
$objRichText->createText(' World.');

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getCell("A1")
    ->setValue($objRichText);
```

Comment: Hi,it works fine.but i need a line breaks in Rich Text.i.e im adding a address kind of in the cell.In that i need underline and line breaks.

Comment: If you want a line break, then use a `"\n"`, though you probably also want to set the cell to autowrap (`$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);`), and probably set the row to autofit height as well (`$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension(1)->setRowHeight(-1);`)